# Android Deep Linking Installs

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

Google recently implemented a [feature](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) into Google Search that allows a user to install your app on the fly if the result can be opened in your app.

Is there any way to detect if this is how your app was opened? Installed and deep linked from a Google Search?

Comment: There is always `getCallingActivity` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29

Answer (score 5):

You can query the Intent extra `android.intent.extra.REFERRER_NAME` in your Activity to check if your app was deep-linked from Google Search.

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/referrer)

> The value of the extra will have one of the following formats,
>   depending on the type of referrer:
>
> **App referrer** — "android-app://{package_id}/{scheme}/{host_path}"
>
> **Web referrer** — "https://{host_path}"

Comment: This is only from the Google app, not from search results in a mobile browser, eh?

Comment: Also from the browser if you are logged in to Google.

Comment: That's interesting, I've not been able to observe any referrer when following a deep link from a browser's Google search results.

Comment: Someone at Google was the first-hand source for that information - I have however not tested it myself and it is possible that they were incorrect.